# How do you get the video data?

Tags: javascript, stream

I want to take the video data and convert it using cv2. Which part is the video data? It's a code that might be related.

I want to send video data from the client to the server using webrtc, and convert and send the converted video from server to cv2 from the client again.

app.js

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room
# Next two lines are for the issue: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-engineio/issues/142
import os

secretKey = os.urandom(24)
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = secretKey
print("secretKey is ",secretKey)

socketio = SocketIO(app)

_users_in_room = {} # stores room wise user list
_room_of_sid = {} # stores room joined by an used
_name_of_sid = {} # stores display name of users

@app.route("/",methods=["GET", "POST"]) #첫번째 로그인화면
def loginPage():
    if request.method == "POST":
        room_id = request.form['room_id']
        return redirect(url_for('enter_room',room_id=room_id))

    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/<string:room_id>/checkpoint/", methods=["GET", "POST"])    #두번째 화면
def entry_checkpoint(room_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        display_name = request.form['display_name']
        mute_video = request.form['mute_video']
        session[room_id] = {"name": display_name, "mute_video":mute_video}
        return redirect(url_for("enter_room", room_id=room_id))

    return render_template("chatroom_checkpoint.html", room_id=room_id)

@app.route("/<string:room_id>/") #세번째 스트림화면
def enter_room(room_id):
    if room_id not in session:
        return redirect(url_for("entry_checkpoint", room_id=room_id))
    return render_template("chatroom.html", room_id=room_id, display_name=session[room_id]["name"], mute_video=session[room_id]["mute_video"])

@socketio.on("connect")
def on_connect():
    sid = request.sid
    print("New socket connected ", sid)
    

@socketio.on("join-room")
def on_join_room(data):
    sid = request.sid
    room_id = data["room_id"]
    display_name = session[room_id]["name"]
    
    # register sid to the room
    join_room(room_id)
    _room_of_sid[sid] = room_id
    _name_of_sid[sid] = display_name
    
    # broadcast to others in the room
    print("[{}] New member joined: {}<{}>".format(room_id, display_name, sid))
    emit("user-connect", {"sid": sid, "name": display_name}, broadcast=True, include_self=False, room=room_id)
    
    # add to user list maintained on server
    if room_id not in _users_in_room:
        _users_in_room[room_id] = [sid]
        emit("user-list", {"my_id": sid}) # send own id only
    else:
        usrlist = {u_id:_name_of_sid[u_id] for u_id in _users_in_room[room_id]}
        emit("user-list", {"list": usrlist, "my_id": sid}) # send list of existing users to the new member
        _users_in_room[room_id].append(sid) # add new member to user list maintained on server

    print("\nusers: ", _users_in_room, "\n")


@socketio.on("disconnect")
def on_disconnect():
    sid = request.sid
    room_id = _room_of_sid[sid]
    display_name = _name_of_sid[sid]

    print("[{}] Member left: {}<{}>".format(room_id, display_name, sid))
    emit("user-disconnect", {"sid": sid}, broadcast=True, include_self=False, room=room_id)

    _users_in_room[room_id].remove(sid)
    if len(_users_in_room[room_id]) == 0:
        _users_in_room.pop(room_id)

    _room_of_sid.pop(sid)
    _name_of_sid.pop(sid)

    print("\nusers: ", _users_in_room, "\n")


@socketio.on("data")
def on_data(data):
    sender_sid = data['sender_id']
    target_sid = data['target_id']
    if sender_sid != request.sid:
        print("[Not supposed to happen!] request.sid and sender_id don't match!!!")

    if data["type"] != "new-ice-candidate":
        print('{} message from {} to {}'.format(data["type"], sender_sid, target_sid))
    socketio.emit('data', data, room=target_sid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port='5050', debug=True)
```

chatroom_networking.js

```
var myID;
var _peer_list = {};

// socketio 
var protocol = window.location.protocol;
var socket = io(protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port, {autoConnect: false});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event)=>{
    startCamera();
});

var camera_allowed=false; 
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true, // We want an audio track
    video: true
}

function startCamera()
{
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints)
    .then((stream)=>{
        myVideo.srcObject = stream;
        camera_allowed = true;
        //start the socketio connection
        socket.connect();
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
        console.log("getUserMedia Error! ", e);
        alert("Error! Unable to access camera or mic! ");
    });
}

socket.on("connect", ()=>{
    console.log("socket connected....");
    socket.emit("join-room", {"room_id": myRoomID});
});
socket.on("disconnect", (data)=>{
    console.log("disconnect");
});
socket.on("user-connect", (data)=>{
    console.log("user-connect ", data);
    let peer_id = data["sid"];
    let display_name = data["name"];
    _peer_list[peer_id] = undefined; // add new user to user list
    addVideoElement(peer_id, display_name);
});
socket.on("user-disconnect", (data)=>{
    console.log("user-disconnect ", data);
    let peer_id = data["sid"];
    closeConnection(peer_id);
    removeVideoElement(peer_id);
});
socket.on("user-list", (data)=>{
    console.log("user list recvd ", data);
    myID = data["my_id"];
    if( "list" in data) // not the first to connect to room, existing user list recieved
    {
        let recvd_list = data["list"];  
        // add existing users to user list
        for(peer_id in recvd_list)
        {
            display_name = recvd_list[peer_id];
            _peer_list[peer_id] = undefined;
            addVideoElement(peer_id, display_name);
        } 
        start_webrtc();
    }    
});

function closeConnection(peer_id)
{
    if(peer_id in _peer_list)
    {
        _peer_list[peer_id].onicecandidate = null;
        _peer_list[peer_id].ontrack = null;
        _peer_list[peer_id].onnegotiationneeded = null;

        delete _peer_list[peer_id]; // remove user from user list
    }
}

function log_user_list()
{
    for(let key in _peer_list)
    {
        console.log(`${key}: ${_peer_list[key]}`);
    }
}

//---------------[ webrtc ]--------------------    

var PC_CONFIG = {
    iceServers: [
        {
            urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302', 
                    'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302',
                    'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'
                ]
        },
    ]
};

function log_error(e){console.log("[ERROR] ", e);}
function sendViaServer(data){socket.emit("data", data);}

socket.on("data", (msg)=>{
    switch(msg["type"])
    {
        case "offer":
            handleOfferMsg(msg);
            break;
        case "answer":
            handleAnswerMsg(msg);
            break;
        case "new-ice-candidate":
            handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg);
            break;
    }
});

function start_webrtc()
{
    // send offer to all other members
    for(let peer_id in _peer_list)
    {
        invite(peer_id);
    }
}

function invite(peer_id)
{
    if(_peer_list[peer_id]){console.log("[Not supposed to happen!] Attempting to start a connection that already exists!")}
    else if(peer_id === myID){console.log("[Not supposed to happen!] Trying to connect to self!");}
    else
    {
        console.log(`Creating peer connection for <${peer_id}> ...`);
        createPeerConnection(peer_id);

        let local_stream = myVideo.srcObject;
        local_stream.getTracks().forEach((track)=>{_peer_list[peer_id].addTrack(track, local_stream);});
    }
}

function createPeerConnection(peer_id)
{
    _peer_list[peer_id] = new RTCPeerConnection(PC_CONFIG);

    _peer_list[peer_id].onicecandidate = (event) => {handleICECandidateEvent(event, peer_id)};
    _peer_list[peer_id].ontrack = (event) => {handleTrackEvent(event, peer_id)};
    _peer_list[peer_id].onnegotiationneeded = () => {handleNegotiationNeededEvent(peer_id)};
}


function handleNegotiationNeededEvent(peer_id)
{
    _peer_list[peer_id].createOffer()
    .then((offer)=>{return _peer_list[peer_id].setLocalDescription(offer);})
    .then(()=>{
        console.log(`sending offer to <${peer_id}> ...`);
        sendViaServer({
            "sender_id": myID,
            "target_id": peer_id,
            "type": "offer",
            "sdp": _peer_list[peer_id].localDescription
        });
    })
    .catch(log_error);
} 

function handleOfferMsg(msg)
{   
    peer_id = msg['sender_id'];

    console.log(`offer recieved from <${peer_id}>`);
    
    createPeerConnection(peer_id);
    let desc = new RTCSessionDescription(msg['sdp']);
    _peer_list[peer_id].setRemoteDescription(desc)
    .then(()=>{
        let local_stream = myVideo.srcObject;
        local_stream.getTracks().forEach((track)=>{_peer_list[peer_id].addTrack(track, local_stream);});
    })
    .then(()=>{return _peer_list[peer_id].createAnswer();})
    .then((answer)=>{return _peer_list[peer_id].setLocalDescription(answer);})
    .then(()=>{
        console.log(`sending answer to <${peer_id}> ...`);
        sendViaServer({
            "sender_id": myID,
            "target_id": peer_id,
            "type": "answer",
            "sdp": _peer_list[peer_id].localDescription
        });
    })
    .catch(log_error);
}

function handleAnswerMsg(msg)
{
    peer_id = msg['sender_id'];
    console.log(`answer recieved from <${peer_id}>`);
    let desc = new RTCSessionDescription(msg['sdp']);
    _peer_list[peer_id].setRemoteDescription(desc)
}


function handleICECandidateEvent(event, peer_id)
{
    if(event.candidate){
        sendViaServer({
            "sender_id": myID,
            "target_id": peer_id,
            "type": "new-ice-candidate",
            "candidate": event.candidate
        });
    }
}

function handleNewICECandidateMsg(msg)
{
    console.log(`ICE candidate recieved from <${peer_id}>`);
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate(msg.candidate);
    _peer_list[msg["sender_id"]].addIceCandidate(candidate)
    .catch(log_error);
}


function handleTrackEvent(event, peer_id)
{
    console.log(`track event recieved from <${peer_id}>`);
    
    if(event.streams)
    {
        getVideoObj(peer_id).srcObject = event.streams[0];
    }
}
```

chatroom_ui.js

```
var myVideo;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event)=>{
    myVideo = document.getElementById("local_vid");

    document.getElementById("room_link").innerHTML=`or the link: <span class="heading-mark">${window.location.href}</span>`;
});


function makeVideoElement(element_id, display_name)
{
    let wrapper_div = document.createElement("div");
    let vid_wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    let vid = document.createElement("video");
    let name_text = document.createElement("div");

    wrapper_div.id = "div_"+element_id;
    vid.id = "vid_"+element_id;

    wrapper_div.className = "shadow video-item";
    vid_wrapper.className = "vid-wrapper";
    
    vid.autoplay = true;        

    vid_wrapper.appendChild(vid);
    wrapper_div.appendChild(vid_wrapper);
    console.log(wrapper_div)
    return wrapper_div;
}

function addVideoElement(element_id)
{        
    document.getElementById("video_grid").appendChild(makeVideoElement(element_id));
}
function removeVideoElement(element_id)
{    
    let v = getVideoObj(element_id);
    if(v.srcObject){
        v.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }
    v.removeAttribute("srcObject");
    v.removeAttribute("src");

    document.getElementById("div_"+element_id).remove();
}

function getVideoObj(element_id)
{
    return document.getElementById("vid_"+element_id);
}
```